# How to Calculate % gained from buy and sell price

Tags: python

My data is showing only the buying price and selling price of one security. Assuming the first data is buy and second is sell, following by third data is buy. 
Eg: [buy 2,sell 3,buy 3.5,sell 4,buy 3,sell 2.8]. How to run a loop to calculate the pct.change() of every 2 row of data? The return should be like [0.5,0.14,-0.25,-0.06]

Comment: Could you please provide an exact input and output. Also elaborate the question a bit properly.

Comment: Also rethink your data format, [buy, sell, buy, sell... ] is just awkward. Something like [(buy, sell), (buy, sell), ...] would be much more reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you this little snippet where the output will be processed in the res array.

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
res = []   
for i in range(0, len(data), 2):
    res.append((data[i+1]/data[i]))
print(res)
```

I have a lot of experience with trading algorithms and I will say that your format is OK for starting out, but if you get into more complicated algorithms you should consider creating a transaction class to hold you transaction information.

Comment: Thanks man! I'm just starting out algorithms trading. You are my man. :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly... you need

```
data = [ 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 3, 2.8]
for val1, val2 in zip(data[::2], data[1::2]):
    print( float(val2 - val1)/val1 )
```

**Output:**

```
0.5
0.142857142857
-0.0666666666667
```